# Euclidean distance in R using two variables in a matrix

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I am quite new to R and I am trying to compute the gross distance (or the sum of the Euclidean distance on all data points) from two variables in my matrix and net distance (Euclidean distance between the first and last point of my data. 
So just a background on my data. My data is normally a csv file comprising of 5 variables: tracks of cells (called A), time interval, X and Y position of each cell, V=velocity. There is around 90 tracks per data and each track should be treated independent of each other.

```
dput(head(t1))
structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), T = 0:5, X = c(668L, 
668L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 668L), Y = c(259L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 
259L, 259L), V = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A", "T", 
"X", "Y", "V"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I was not aware of the dist() function before, so I made my own function:

```
GD.data <- function (trackdata)
{A= trackdata(, 1); V=trackdata(, 5);
 for (i in min(A):max(A))
   while (A<=i) {GD(i) = (sum (V)*(1/25))
                 return (GD(i))}
```

This did not work. I used A as an identifier of the track and since gross distance could be also computed as:
distance=velocity (t1-t0), I just did summation of all velocity times my time interval (since it is constantly 1/25 secs.

How do I use the dist() function with my A as identifier? I need this since the computation of each track should be separate. Thanks!

Comment: [Related and possibly helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996141/calculate-total-miles-traveled-from-vectors-of-lat-lon/13996278#13996278)

Comment: Thanks! But he is computing from one driver (track) only. What if computing with many tracks in one matrix (in his case, many drivers)? Thanks

Comment: When you say *didn't work* what error messages did you get? I am assuming at least *argument "x" is missing, with no default* ? You have a dataframe (`trackdata`) and are trying to reference the columns using e.g. `(,1)`. You need to use `[` which is the subsetting function - i.e. `trackdata[,1]` will get you the first column. HTH!

Comment: It would help a lot if you would post the output from `dput(head(trackdata))` into your question as a code block, then we can recreate a small sample of your data on our computers.

Comment: @SimonO101 When I run it on the console, it sorts of wait for another command because the arrow does not show up. So I don't know if it really does not work or if I end it the wrong way.

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc you are missing a curly brace in your code. It also will not work because you have not defined `GD` and you use `()` to try to reference an element in that vector. There are a few problems to sort out which I am sure many people will be only too happy to help with, but we need to see the structure of your data first. Welcome to SO btw.

Comment: Karen, as SimonO101 pointed out, you need to learn `R` 's syntax. Right now we can't even tell if `trackdata` is properly assembled.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks! I cant post a picture of what my data looks like. How do I define GD if its already in the while loop?

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc no don't add a picture! Try running these commands `dat <- read.csv("path/to/file/myfile.csv" , h = TRUE ) ; dput( head( dat ) )` puttig in the filepath to your datafile (sorry if this is obvious but I don't know how much experience you have). This will let us copy and paste a small amount of your data into our R sessions and recreate it *exactly* as you have it on your computer.

Comment: @SimonO101 is what I did correct (see edited post?) Thanks for helping out. I am really new in creating functions.

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc yes it is. Now wait a little while and someone is bound to be able to help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have velocity measured at constant time intervals, which you can sum over to get the total euclidean distance moved, you can actually just use the `base` R function `aggregate` to sum the `V` data by each track identifier `A`, which is what the command below does:

```
aggregate( V ~ A , data = t1 , sum , na.rm = TRUE )
```

Basically this says, `aggregate` V for each value of A. The aggregation function is `sum` (you can imagine this could easily be the `mean` velocity for each track by using `mean` instead of sum). We pass an additional argument to `sum` which is `na.rm`, telling it to ignore NAs in the data (which I assume are at `t = 0` for each track).

**Calculating 'as the crow flies' distance  between first and last position by track:**

For this we can `split` the dataframe into sub-dataframes by the track identifier `A` and then operate on each subset of the data, using `lapply` to apply a simple hypotenuse calculation to the first and last row of each sub-dataframe.

```
## Split the data
dfs <- split(t1,t1$A)

## Find hypotenuse between first and last rows for each A
lapply( dfs , function(x){
  j <- nrow(x)
  str <- x[1,c("X","Y")]
  end <- x[j,c("X","Y")]
  dist <- sqrt( sum( (end - str)^2 ) )
  return( dist )
} )
```

Comment: It works! Thank you, it worked! But I also need the net distance (distance from last point to first point), that's why I also asked about the dist() function. Can you also help on this? Thank you.

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc as in the straightline distance between the first and last point of a track?

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc you should probably ask that as another question but I will paste a solution into this question. Also, since you are new here, you may find it helpful to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to help you get the most out of the site!

Comment: thanks a lot (not just for the answer but also for welcoming me into this community!)