# Distances between consecutive points

Tags: r

I have a data frame with longitude and latitude data, and I want to calculate the distance between every consecutive points.

I have found that `distm` from the geosphere package calculates the distance, but it requires as an input longitude/latitude (can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude, second is latitude) or a `SpatialPoints*` object) from two successive points.

```
distm(x, y, fun=distHaversine)
```

How can I generate `x` and `y`?

### Edit:

For @Josh O'Brien comment:

pts

```
lon   lat

30.5 -42.5  
31.5 -42.5  
32.5 -43.5  
33.5 -43.5
35.5 -43.5
```

I get

segDists

```
82198.54  137803.62   80876.19  161749.47
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are in your data.frame.   `dat$lon` and `dat$lat`.   I am not familiar with `distm`, it might requrie the use of `apply(dat, 1, function(x) distm(x$lon, x$lat))`  or something similar

Comment: Do you require a complicated answer that knows about curvature of earth e.g NY to Moscow, or just a simple one that calculates euclidean between consecutive points NY to NJ?

Comment: For the basic idea, [see my response here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996141/calculate-total-miles-traveled-from-vectors-of-lat-lon/13996278#13996278) to an essentially identical question.

Comment: Hi, I don't know why but it is not giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data as dat:

```
sapply(2:nrow(dat),function(i){distm(dat[i-1,],dat[i,])})
#  [1]  82072.86 137911.46  80747.82 161492.73
```

Which is the same result as @JoshObrien if you substitute `distHaversine(...)` for `distVincentyEllipsoid(...)` in his code snippet.