# Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : latitude > 90

Tags: r

I am trying to use the distVincentyEllipsoid function in the geosphere package in R to calculate the distance between different points in my data frame, following the example given at [Calculate total miles traveled from vectors of lat / lon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996141/calculate-total-miles-traveled-from-vectors-of-lat-lon). However, I keep getting the error "Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : latitude > 90", even though all my latitudes are much less than 90. what could be the problem? Please help

Comment: Demonstrate that your lon-lat input really does have latitudes in that range. My guess is you have the order wrong. The pointsToMatrix source is not complicated btw

Comment: If we call whatever you are using as the first argument to `distVincentyEllipsoid(...)` `p1`, then type `range(p1[2])`. If either of the numbers output is >90, that's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same issue. Check to see if you input the data as c(LONG, LAT). I had made the mistake of using the more common format of c(LAT, LONG).

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that you should check for NAs. I geocoded a set of zip codes to coordinates and since some of the zips were out of date (at least that's what I think happened), they failed to generate coordinates.

If you run:

```
range(p1[2])
```

and get

```
NA NA
```

then that's a pretty go indication.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, solved with as.numeric :

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
Lieu1 <- c(args[1],args[2]) 
Lieu2 <- c(args[3],args[4]) 

Lieu1 <- as.numeric(Lieu1)
Lieu2 <- as.numeric(Lieu2)

library(geosphere)
distVincentyEllipsoid(Lieu1,Lieu2)/1000
```