# Calculating average speed from lon/lat and timestamp using distance (geosphere) and difftime

Tags: r, timestamp, rows, geospatial, distance

I am trying to figure out the haversine distance between two consecutive instances (rows) using the distm function from geosphere. Ultimately, i would like to calculate the average speed using the distance in meters divided by the time difference in seconds.

This is how I've calculated the time difference in seconds

```
df$Timediff_secs <- 
  with(df, 
       difftime(Timestamp, ave(Timestamp, ID, FUN=lag), units='secs'))
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996278/8114224) has been asked before and the answer does work but I need to index by ID so that each new ID starts with NA. I would like to create a new column called `df$Distance`.

This needs to be edited so that it indexes by ID and so that the first row is NA (since there's no difference in distance to be calculated)

```
library(geosphere)
metersPerMile <- 1609.34
pts <- df1[c("lon", "lat")]

## Pass in two derived data.frames that are lagged by one point
segDists <- distVincentyEllipsoid(p1 = pts[-nrow(df),], 
                                  p2 = pts[-1,])
sum(segDists)/metersPerMile
# [1] 1013.919
```

Here is some sample data I copied from the link

```
> df
          Timestamp      ID      lat       lon
2012-11-12 02:08:41      1  76.57169 -110.8070
2012-11-12 02:09:41      1  76.44325 -110.7525
2012-11-12 02:10:41      1  76.90897 -110.8613
2012-11-12 03:18:41      2  76.11152 -110.2037
2012-11-12 03:19:41      2  76.29013 -110.3838
2012-11-12 03:20:41      2  76.15544 -110.4506
```

Feels like I've tried everything, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::lag` or `data.table::shift` and grouping is handy for this, though it can be done manually in base with something like `c(NA, variable[-length(variable)])` and `aggregate`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1352704121, 1352704181, 1352704241, 1352708321, 1352708381, 1352708441), 
                                           class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                     ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                     lat = c(76.57169, 76.44325, 76.90897, 76.11152, 76.29013, 76.15544), 
                     lon = c(-110.807, -110.7525, -110.8613, -110.2037, -110.3838, -110.4506)), 
                class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Timestamp", "ID", "lat", "lon"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df <- df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(dist_m = geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(cbind(lon, lat), 
                                                     cbind(lag(lon), lag(lat))), 
           time_s = difftime(Timestamp, lag(Timestamp), units = 'secs'), 
           speed_m_per_s = dist_m / as.integer(time_s))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>             Timestamp    ID      lat       lon   dist_m  time_s speed_m_per_s
#>                <dttm> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <time>         <dbl>
#> 1 2012-11-12 02:08:41     1 76.57169 -110.8070       NA NA secs            NA
#> 2 2012-11-12 02:09:41     1 76.44325 -110.7525 14408.23 60 secs      240.1371
#> 3 2012-11-12 02:10:41     1 76.90897 -110.8613 52065.53 60 secs      867.7588
#> 4 2012-11-12 03:18:41     2 76.11152 -110.2037       NA NA secs            NA
#> 5 2012-11-12 03:19:41     2 76.29013 -110.3838 20507.15 60 secs      341.7859
#> 6 2012-11-12 03:20:41     2 76.15544 -110.4506 15140.03 60 secs      252.3338
```

Since the data.frame is already grouped, aggregation only requires summing:

```r
df_avg <- df %>% 
    summarise(dist_m = sum(dist_m, na.rm = TRUE), 
              time_s = sum(as.integer(time_s), na.rm = TRUE), 
              speed_m_per_s = dist_m / time_s)

df_avg
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>      ID   dist_m time_s speed_m_per_s
#>   <int>    <dbl>  <int>         <dbl>
#> 1     1 66473.76    120      553.9480
#> 2     2 35647.18    120      297.0598
```

Units are in meters per second; convert as you like.

Comment: Works like a charm, except that the first value for ID = 2 does not start with NA, now it's 90653.24 because it just continues, it should start calculating again from the first instance for each ID. Really appreciate your help @alistaire

Comment: I had just figured out the grouping part but stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to comment, sorry about that. Again, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hope I'm not pushing my luck here @alistaire@amatsuo_net ;) but I was wondering if you could help me with a minor issue trying to index on a binary feature. The indexing only works for the first 1 or 0 in the column, but I need the function to index every time the row value changes to 1 or 0. I have solved a similar issue when indexing on days of the week by making them numerical since each day only occurs once a month, instead of say "Monday" which occurs say 4 times. Know what I mean? Is there a simple solution to this problem? Appreciate your help, again!

Comment: Sounds like `rle` ("run length encoding") or `data.table::rleid`. There are a number of questions on here about it if you search, but if you can't find a similar one, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried rle but I'm not sure I'm incorporating it correctly.. for instance, if we look at the code you posted above, if the grouped by feature "ID" were a binary feature, how would I use rle in that exact average speed function.. Thanks

Comment: That is not the same question as what you asked above. If it's not a duplicate of an existing question, ask it in a new one. If you're trying to group by run, use `data.table::rleid`, as I already said.

Comment: Got it, all I had to do was place rleid in front of the binary variable I was indexing on!

Answer (score 1):

If you are inclined to do with `data.table` here is how:

```
df[, Timestamp := parse_datetime(Timestamp)]
df[, distance := distVincentyEllipsoid(p1 = cbind(lon, lat), 
                                       p2 = cbind(shift(lon), shift(lat))), 
   by = ID]
output <- df[, .(time_diff = as.numeric(Timestamp[.N] - Timestamp[1], unit = "secs") ,
                 tot_distance = sum(distance, na.rm = TRUE)), by = ID]
output[, avg_speed := tot_distance /time_diff]
##    ID time_diff tot_distance avg_speed
## 1:  1       120     66473.26  553.9438
## 2:  2       120     35646.55  297.0546
```